# gcc and clang don't emit a warning when returning a pointer to a compound literal

Tags: c, compound-literals

Based on the explanation of https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/compound_literal:

> The unnamed object to which the compound literal evaluates has static
>   storage duration if the compound literal occurs at file scope **and
>   automatic storage duration if the compound literal occurs at block
>   scope** (in which case the object's lifetime ends at the end of the
>   enclosing block).

But this piece of code compiles (and works) fine without warnings (all warnings on) in both gcc and clang:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {int first; int second;} int_pair;

static int_pair *pair(int a, int b)
{
    return &(int_pair){a, b};
}

int main(void)
{
    int_pair *x = pair(1, 2);

    printf("%d %d\n", x->first, x->second);
    return 0;
}
```

As far as I understand, this piece of code is the same as:

```
static int_pair *pair(int a, int b)
{
    int_pair x = {a, b};

    return &x;
}
```

Which returns:

```
warning: function returns address of local variable [-Wreturn-local-addr]
     return &x;
```

Comment: Yes, the problem is indeed the same in both cases. Apparently GCC and Clang allow compound literals to slip through their checks. C compiler in MSVS catches the problem in both cases.

Comment: @ David C. Rankin : "...to a statically declared function"? As the OP said, this is an ordinary compound literal - a nameless automatic object.

Comment: @AnT _C compiler in MSVS catches the problem in both cases._, thanks for pointing that, I didn't know that VS has support for C99

Comment: @KeineLust *almost* all of it now (only took 18 years).

Comment: Support for C99 has been present in Visual Studio compiler for quite a while already.